# Can't call method "headers" on an undefined value at search.pl line 10

Tags: perl, mojolicious

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Mojo::Base -strict;
use Mojo::DOM;
use Mojo::Util qw(decode);
use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $uri = 'http://efremova.info/word/statja.html';
my $sel = 'td#centerCnt ol li';
my $charset = 'windows-1251';
my $tx = Mojo::UserAgent->new()->get($uri);
my $res->headers->content_type("text/html; charset=$charset");
my $dom = $res->dom;
my $el = $dom->at($sel) or die "selector $sel not found";
$el->find('span.nobr')->each(sub { $_->replace($_->text) });
my $text = $el->text;
binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
```

get error: Can't call method "headers" on an undefined value at search.pl line 10.

what should I do?

Thanks a lot

Comment: retagged `mojo` to `mojolicious` because this is the name of the web framework you're using here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget that, you need to first get res from tx.

```
my $tx = Mojo::UserAgent->new()->get($uri);

my $res = $tx->res;

$res->headers->content_type("text/html; charset=$charset");
my $dom = $res->dom;
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable declarations with `my` are structured like this:

```
my [TYPE] NAME [ATTRIBUTES] [= EXPRESSION]
```

(bracketed parts are optional.)

When you just do `my $name`, you declare a new variable but haven't yet assigned to it, so the value is `undef`. Do note that inside the expression, the variable that is being defined isn't accessible.

The expression `undef eq (my $undef)` evaluates to true: The value of the new variable is `undef`.
Actually, declarations are expressions themselves, returning Lvalues.

```
$ perl -Mstrict -E'my $three = my $foo + 2 + (my $bar=1); say $three'
3
```

In non-strict mode, you could say `my $weird = $weird + 2`, which would evaluate to `2`. In strict mode, this isn't allowed unless you have a global variable with the same name.

Your syntax `my $undefined->method_call` is a bit unusual and evaluates to `(undef)->method_call` which *isn't possible* (except with autoboxing).

The solution:

1. `use strict; use warnings;`
2. Declare and initialize your variable first, then call methods on it.

In this special case, to *retrieve* the content type, you could do

```
my $content_type = $tx->res->headers->content_type;
```

Setting the content type does not carry any meaning. To retrieve the DOM, you could do

```
my $dom = $tx->res->dom;
```

If you like long method chains, you could do

```
my $el =
   Mojo::UserAgent->new()
     ->get($uri)
     ->dom
     ->at($sel)
   or die "..."
;;
```

Documentation on the Mojo Modules:

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Transaction::HTTP](http://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aTransaction%3a%3aHTTP)

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent](http://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent)

Documentation on `my`:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html (Following the links is recommended)